Importing Data with csv
(In Jupyter Notebook)
raw_data_np = np.genfromtxt("loan-data.csv", delimiter = ';', skip_header = 1, autostrip = True)
raw_data_np

the error is: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 341: illegal multibyte sequence

You have promised numpy that your file is in the GBK character set, which includes Chinese/Japanese/Korean, but your file does NOT seem to be in that format.  You need t know exactly what character set was used to create the file.
